# Angular2 Notifying the template of a change

Tags: angular

Here is my code :

```
@Component({
    selector: "foo",
    template: `
      <span>Init : {{o.init}}</span>
      <span>Loaded data : {{o.loadedData}}</span>
    `,
    providers: [
        Services
    ]
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit{
   constructor (private _services: Services) {}

   o: Object
   ngOnInit() {
      o = {"init": "foo"}
      this.services.randomCall()
          .subscribe(
              res => this.o["loadedData"] = res["loadedData"]  
          )
   }
}
```

So `o.loadedData` doesn't appear everytime due to a race condition between my `randomCall()` and the template rendering. What I would like would be to notify angular after having assigned `o["loadedData"] = res["loadedData"]`. In angular1, I would have done a call to the scope's `digest()` function.

How can I do something similar in angular2 ?

Thanks !

Edit: I added back this, it was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `this` keyword:

```
o: Object
ngOnInit() {
  this.o = {"init": "foo"}; // <-----

  this.services.randomCall()
      .subscribe(
          res => {
            this.o["loadedData"] = res["loadedData"]; // <-----
          }
      );
 }
```

**Edit**

You could force Angular2 to detect changes using the ChangeDetectorRef class, this way:

```
constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

o: Object
ngOnInit() {
  this.o = {"init": "foo"};

  this.services.randomCall()
      .subscribe(
          res => {
            this.o["loadedData"] = res["loadedData"];
            this.cdr.detectChanges(); // <-----
          }
      );
 }
```

Comment: My bad, it was a typo in my stackoverflow case, not in my actual one.

Comment: Okay no problem! You could leverage the `ChangeDetectorRef` class and its `detectChanges` method. Normally it's not necessary...

Comment: What is the content of the `randomCall` method?

Answer (score 2):

Normally this is done by Angulars change detection which gets notified by its zone that change detection should happen. When code that somehow runs outside Angulars zone modifies your model, then you can invoke change detection manually like

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit{
   constructor (private _services: Services, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

   o: Object
   ngOnInit() {
      o = {"init": "foo"}
      this.services.randomCall()
          .subscribe(
              res => {
                  o["loadedData"] = res["loadedData"];
                  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
              });
          )
   }
}
```

*Because of the missing `this` as mentioned by Thierry, manual change detection won't help you in this case anyway.*

For more options how to invoke change detection see [Triggering Angular2 change detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)